# The number of checkboxes checked

Tags: java, android

I have 4 checkboxes and i try to show on TextView how many is checked.
I Created a variable numberOfTrue and i increase this in switch.
Of course my app no working now, the textView still show "0"
 The variable does not refresh after changing the number of clicked boxes, what i should fix now ?
 I have no idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private int numberOfTrue = 0;
    private TextView tv1;
    private CheckBox cb1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CheckBox cb2,cb3,cb4;
        Button b2;


        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb1.setChecked(getFromSP("cb1"));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        cb2.setChecked(getFromSP("cb2"));
        cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        cb3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        cb3.setChecked(getFromSP("cb3"));
        cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        cb4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb4);
        cb4.setChecked(getFromSP("cb4"));
        cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        tv1.setText(""+numberOfTrue);


        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();

            }
        });



    }


    private boolean getFromSP(String key){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    }
    private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }



    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        switch(buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.cb1:
                saveInSp("cb1",isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true){
                    numberOfTrue++;
            }
                break;
            case R.id.cb2:
                saveInSp("cb2",isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true){
                    numberOfTrue++;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.cb3:
                saveInSp("cb3",isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true){
                    numberOfTrue++;
                }
                break;

            case R.id.cb4:
                saveInSp("cb4",isChecked);
                if (isChecked == true){
                    numberOfTrue++;
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707204/introduction-of-sharedpreference-in-tap-counter-app-causes-app-crash/44707237#44707237 , you have the same issue

Comment: yea, better, but my app still show "0" in textView, no get a update

Comment: a edit my  problem a little now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Follow the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707204/introduction-of-sharedpreference-in-tap-counter-app-causes-app-crash/44707237#44707237) , which says use strings with `TextView` like `tv1.setText(""+numberOfTrue);`

2.)  add `tv1.setText(""+numberOfTrue);` at the end of `onCheckedChanged(` function to reflect new values in your `textview` after the `checkChange` event

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // switch code
        tv1.setText(""+numberOfTrue); 
   }
```

Comment: much better, but i can click 100 times on 1 checkbox and i see number 100 in textView :/

Comment: just add an `else` statement along with every if and use `else{ numberOfTrue--; }`